# Distribute time among multiple records for same person for same day (loop)

Tags: sql, sql-server

*** Updated Request ***

I've records that shows some work hours for few employees, Most of the time they will only have one record per day which is REG, sometimes they will have more than one a day like REG and OT or REG, OT, and OT1.  First part of my task is to take the hours and match the hours to another table (which includes break time) and take the corresponding break time and then deduct the break time from actual hours and display the result.  I've successfully done this already.  ***Second part of the task is IF there are more than 1 record a day like REG, OT or REG, OT, OT1 then I have to sum the total hours (reg,ot,ot1) then go the break table and find the corresponding break, then multiply the break in hours (break / 60) with each record for that day then divide it by the sum, take this value and subtract that from actual amount***.  following are the example (I'm guessing I need some kind of loop for this)

***Hours data Table***

```
EMP_ID    DATE         HOUR TYPE   HOUR
--------  ----------   ----------  ----------
1234      8/1/17       REG         8
2345      8/1/17       REG         5
3456      8/1/17       REG         8
3456      8/1/17       OT          1
4567      8/1/17       REG         8
4567      8/1/17       OT          1
4567      8/1/17       OT1         2
```

***Break data Table***

```
HOUR_TYPE    FROM_HR_1   TO_HR_1    BREAK_IN_MIN_1  FROM_HR_2   TO_HR_2    BREAK_IN_MIN_2    FROM_HR_2   TO_HR_2    BREAK_IN_MIN_2
-----------  ----------  ---------  --------------- ----------  ---------  ---------------   ----------  ---------  ---------------
REG          0           5          20              6            8         40                9            12         60
OT           0           5          0               6            8         40                9            12         60
OT1          0           5          0               6            8         0                 9            12         40
```

***Current Result Table***

```
EMP_ID    DATE         HOUR TYPE   ACT_HOUR   ADJ_HOUR 
--------  ----------   ----------  ---------  ---------
1234      8/1/17       REG         8          7.34
2345      8/1/17       REG         5          4.67
3456      8/1/17       REG         8          7.34
3456      8/1/17       OT          1          1
4567      8/1/17       REG         8          7.34
4567      8/1/17       OT          1          1
4567      8/1/17       OT1         2          2
```

***EXPECTED Result Table***

```
EMP_ID    DATE         HOUR TYPE   ACT_HOUR   ADJ_HOUR 
--------  ----------   ----------  ---------  ---------
1234      8/1/17       REG         8          7.34
2345      8/1/17       REG         5          4.67
3456      8/1/17       REG         8          7.12
3456      8/1/17       OT          1          .89
4567      8/1/17       REG         8          7.28
4567      8/1/17       OT          1          .91
4567      8/1/17       OT1         2          1.82
```

As you can see the "EXPECTED Result Table" I need to take the break time split based on the above formula 
Thank you in advance for helping me figure this out.

Comment: why is the resulting adj_hour rows 3 and 5 became 6.30? shouldn't it be 7.30 (7hours and 30mins/7.5hours)?

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar You are absolutely correct!!! that was a mistake on my part

Comment: don't you have a record in break table for OT and OT1, just REG?

Comment: Yes there is but those are if anything more than 5 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you cannot use an aggregate function in an update query, you will need to use a derived table (a subquery would also work). My answer assumes you have a `hours` table and a `breaks` table, and that there is a row in breaks for every employee/date.

Try something along these lines:

```
update 
    hours
set
    ADJ_HOUR = 
    round(
        ADJ_HOUR -
            -- Build the value to subtract from ADJ_HOUR:
            (
                (b.BREAK_IN_MIN_1 + b.BREAK_IN_MIN_2) -- Sum of the breaks
                / (convert(float, cnt.total_rows) -- Divide the minutes by the num of "hours" rows
            )
            / convert(float, 60) -- Divide the subtract amount by 60 (minutes)
    , 1) -- Round to 1 decimal place
from 
    hours h
    join breaks b 
        on (h.employee=b.employee and h.date=b.date) -- Get the breaks for each employee
     -- Get the num of hour rows:
    join (select employee, date, count(*) as total_rows from hours group by employee_date) as cnt 
        on (h.employee=cnt.employee and h.date=cnt.date)
```

Note about all the `convert(float...)` calls: When doing division where you expect a float value to come from dividing two integers, you need to convert/cast one of the values to float. Otherwise, the optimizer sets the datatype to be the same as the two dividing values (two int datatypes produce an int).

Comment: Thank you RToyota,  As you saw I DO have a table with all the hours table with employee date and a separate table for breaks with just general hours not specif for emp.  I'm inserting the data into a 3rd table with combined result. My Current result set is doing the necessary conversion of  min to hours and minus the mins from hours and adding to adjusted column.. the issue i have is when there is more than 1 record a day, then i'm not sure how to evenly distribute the time.  I'll take a look at your solution and let you know how i do

Comment: unfortunately this won't work for me.  Because my Break table doesn't have employee id.  its a generic reference table.  For example, if my hours are 8 from "Hours table" then i try to see if my 8 falls under give hours in the mins table, and it it does take the mins from that line and do the math.